# Parsing Special Characters - Function Mysql 5.5?

Tags: php, mysql

I comment that I have a problem when trying to create a function to parse special characters, and call recursively.

Mysql code:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_obt_val_par_campo;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION fn_obt_val_par_campo(campo VARCHAR(80))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(80)
BEGIN

    DECLARE par_campo VARCHAR(80);
    DECLARE for_campo VARCHAR(80);
    DECLARE ind_campo INT DEFAULT 1;

    SET for_campo = LOWER(campo);

    WHILE ind_campo = 1 DO

        IF INSTR(for_campo, 'á') != 0 THEN
            SET par_campo = UPPER(REPLACE(for_campo, 'á', 'a'));
            SET for_campo = par_campo;
            SET ind_campo = 1;
        ELSEIF INSTR(for_campo, 'é') != 0 THEN
            SET par_campo = UPPER(REPLACE(for_campo, 'é', 'e'));
            SET ind_campo = 1;
        ELSEIF INSTR(for_campo, 'í') != 0 THEN
            SET par_campo = UPPER(REPLACE(for_campo, 'í', 'i'));
            SET ind_campo = 1;
        ELSEIF INSTR(for_campo, 'ó') != 0 THEN
            SET par_campo = UPPER(REPLACE(for_campo, 'ó', 'o'));
            SET ind_campo = 1;
        ELSEIF INSTR(for_campo, 'ú') != 0 THEN
            SET par_campo = UPPER(REPLACE(for_campo, 'ú', 'u'));
            SET ind_campo = 1;
        ELSE
            SET par_campo = UPPER(for_campo);
            SET ind_campo = 0;
        END IF;

    END WHILE;

    RETURN par_campo;

END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Consultation never ends, and the connection is blocked mysql:

```
SELECT fn_obt_val_par_campo('ALVARZ') AS CAMPO
```

I hope you can help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with special chars:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_obt_val_par_campo(campo VARCHAR(80))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(80);
                       ^---this is the error
BEGIN
```

There is no delimiter allowed between create/begin, that's all.

Comment: OP already has `delimiter $$`. problem is that no matter what you change the delimiter to, a delimiter is NOT PERMITTED to be where OP has one. it's a flat-out syntax error because it's an illegal place to be using ANY delimiter

Comment: Friend modify my query, please if I can support the Mysql query